# Show that ($\mathscr{P}(\Bbb{R})$)' and $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ are isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Apologies for any bad formatting.

This is number 35 from chapter 3.F of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, if you have the text to view.

I've been stuck on this one for quite some time:
obviously because the vector spaces are infinite dimensional, we cannot create the isomorphism using bases of the spaces. Also, because $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ contains infinite sequences, it is not clear to me how to create an injective function...

I also thought that maybe I could develop the isomorphism using finite dimensional subspaces of the respective spaces, which is relatively easy, but being able to abstract that iso for the infinite dimensional spaces is beyond me.

Any assistance/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What do you mean by $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) )'$ ?

Comment: Thank you ! @AndreaMarino. $(\mathscr{P}(R))')$ is the dual space of $\mathscr{P}(R)$, i.e $\mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P}(R),\Bbb{F})$

Comment: Possibly! @azif00 I ended up creating a proof of the isomorphism in a similar manner, but its a bit iffy... I'll spare repeating the information about why, but you can view my replies to Chris below if you're still curious.

Answer (score 1):

As with all algebraic duals, the correspondence is based on looking at how each functional behaves on a basis for the original vector space (in your case, polynomials). So let $\beta = \{1, t, t^2, \ldots\}$ be the standard monomial basis for the space of real polynomials. Then, by linearity, every linear functional $L \in (P(R))'$ is uniquely defined by its values on $\beta$, namely $L(1), L(t), L(t^2), \ldots$. Perhaps, more suggestively, let $L(1) = a_0, L(t) = a_1, \ldots, L(t^k) = a_k$. Then $L$ is determined by a set $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$. Because it sounds like you are a new student, it might be helpful that I leave some remaining details for you to work out, namely making sure that this correspondence is both injective and surjective.

Comment: $\mathscr{P}(R)$ is infinite dimensional, so, based off my understanding, it cannot have a basis, as a basis is a list (finite length) of linearly independent vectors (in this case polynomials) that span the space. Thus any list (1,x,x^2,...x^n) could not span the vector space, as a polynomial of degree n+1 cannot be created from the span... that's just based off Axler's textbook definitions. I ended up proving the problem using a similar "basis" as you described, but, again, based off the textbook definitions, no such basis can be created for an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Once some kind of "basis" can be used, the proof of well defined, linearity, and the isomorphism are relatively simple.. my issue is that I'm not certain its "legal" to use the basis you described (even though I did for the proof) because of the textbook definitions Axler has about the necessity of the spanning list/set being finite in length. I ended up using that monomial "basis" for my proof, as the crucial characteristics of linear independence and span are preserved, but it violates Axler's definition of the basis as its not finite length.

Comment: I am not familiar with Axler's book, but an infinite-dimensional vector space is precisely one that has a basis of infinite size. Every polynomial is a linear combination of monomials, so by definition the space of polynomials must have $\{1, t, t^2, \ldots\}$ as its basis.